# How would we integrating high energy part of a relativistic quantum field theory to get a non-relativistic theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, effective-field-theory

Relativistic quantum field theory (RQFT) is a after spring of quantum theory and special relativity. A novel thing in RQFT is the existence of anti-particle. That is, consider a relativistic field $\phi(x)$, it consist combination of particle operator and anti-particle operator,
$$\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32E_p}}(a_pe^{ip\cdot x}+b_p^*e^{-ip\cdot x})$$
here $a_p$ annihilates a one particle state with 4-momentum $p^\mu$and $b_p^*$ create a one anti-particle state with 4 momentum $p^\mu$.

In another way, the non relativistic field theory, the particle and its anti-particle have their own field, that means two field operator
$$\psi(x)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}}a_p e^{ip\cdot x}, \ \ \ \bar\psi(x)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}}b_p e^{ip\cdot x}$$
don't have to appear in form of $\psi(x)+\bar\psi(x)$.

My question is, how can we integrating out the high speed part in RQFT to get a NRQFT where the particle field and anti-particle field are separated out?

Ref:Introduction to Effective Field Theory C. P. BURGESS

Comment: Without relativity you can't turn mass into energy as per annihilation, or vice versa as per pair creation, so the particle/antiparticle species wouldn't share a field. So what would it mean to say "this is an antiparticle"? Much less than usual (e.g. "this coincidentally has an electron's mass & spin but the opposite charge").

Comment: like electrons and holes in band theory

Comment: Oh, that's _very_ different!

Comment: By non-relativistic I mean the (anti)particles move very slow so that relativistic correction is small. So there is still relativity, though their effect on spectrum is negligible small.